# Script runs on terminal, but not as cron

Tags: python, macos, cron, sh

I have a shell script that calls a python script, on a mac.  If I run that from the commandline, it runs fine.  If I do the same from a cron job, I get the error `"env: python3: No such file or directory"`.  The shebang line in python script is `"#!/usr/bin/env python3"`.

If I change the shebang line to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` I get

```
import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

Do not know if it matters, I have installed python using homebrew.

Thank you for any suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` searches using the `PATH` variable. If `/usr/local/bin` isn't in the default `PATH`, it won't find `python3`.

Comment: Does your `.bashrc` set any Python-related env variables?

Comment: I believe cron commands are executed with `sh`.  What shell do you normally use?

Comment: @Barmar - yes, /usr/local/bin is in the default $PATH.  I do not have a default .bashrc file.

Comment: @JohnGordon - The default shell is bash

echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: The default `PATH` for cron jobs is just `/usr/bin:/bin`, so if you want to run anything outside of those directories you need to either use an explicit path to the binary, or set the `PATH` variable in the crontab file. There may be other things missing from the environment of your cron jobs -- the default environment is really minimal, and it doesn't run any of your shell init files.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Do you have a suggestion, how can I achieve it? Or how to add the path to the cron job  ? Thanks

Comment: I added PATH= variable at top of crontab and that seems to have worked.  I will test some more and add that as answer unless @GordonDavisson you want to add your comment as answer with a statement to add PATH variable on top of the crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment above from @GordonDavisson:

> The default PATH for cron jobs is just `/usr/bin:/bin`, so if you want
> to run anything outside of those directories you need to either use an
> explicit path to the binary, or set the PATH variable in the crontab
> file.

I added the statement `PATH=` to the top of crontab and it works.